# How to animate the call to setView in BingMaps?

Tags: javascript, animation, bing-maps

I have the following code, which works, but the zoom is very abrupt.

```
map.setView({zoom: 14});
```

I am trying to provide a smooth zoom, similar to what the map control already provide by clicking on the +/- buttons.  In 2016, @rbrundritt [indicated](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/93a2d940-d468-4e70-a06e-610c04105022/set-zoom-level-with-setview-with-animation-in-v8?forum=bingmapsajax) that while the feature was not available at the moment, the team was looking into it.

I've looked over the documentation and but don't see anything obvious.  Has the situation changed since 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ready through that post you linked to you, you will see I said this is planned for early 2018.